# Find Interchange in Bus Routes Using neo4j

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, neo4j

[image] 
Refer screenshot - Shortest Path A to D

I have one graph with lot of nodes representing stops of buses. There are buses which are associate to bus stops.
I am able to find shortest path(refe direction) from A to G as distance as weight .
Now i have to find combinations of availabale buses which can help user to reach destination.

1) I am able to find common bus if exist.

2) How to find interchnage buses programatically

**Example - A(Source) to G(Destination)**

**A-------->B------>C------>D---->E----->F-------->G**

Following are the buses available at each bus stope -

**Stop.**    -     **ServiceNo(Buses).**

**A  -  120,147,196,197,167,961,961C**

**B  - 12,2,2A,121,122,124,147,166,174,196,197,54,167,190,61,961,961C,143**

**C  - 12,12e,2,2A,121,122,124,147,166,174,174e,196,197,54,CT18,CT8,167,
      190,61,961,961C,143**

**D  -  124,147,147e,166,197,61,961,961C,143**

**E  -  12,12e,2,2A,197,33,63,80,CT18,CT8,61,961,961C,970,143**

**F  -  12,12e,2,2A,174,174e,197,33,51,63,80,61,961,961C**

**G  -  174,174e,186,51,143**

Nodes in Graph have info about buses for each route.So how can i find out the busses( If no direct bus is available) to reach A to G?

**1) A-->F (by 961,961C) then F-->G (by 174 or 174e).**

**2) A--->D by (197,147,961) then D-->F( by 961 or 961C) and then F-->G(by 174 or 174e)etc.**

The problem is, how programmatically check whether a direct bus to G is available or not , or where I to interchange the bus in between.

Is there any cypher query to do this task.

I have to find best 4 possible solutions with minimum number of interchange.

Comment: How exactly are routes modeled in the graph? Are there relationships between these stop nodes that represent a segment of each individual bus route? For a graph problem, modeling routes per bus would probably work best, as you could then do a match from your start node to end node (with an upper bound) and use `reduce()` on the relationships of the path to get the number of interchanges, then sort by distance and interchanges.

Comment: @InverseFalcon...
Yes, I have created routes per bus(serviceNo).
stopes are connected based on bus route sequence no.
I tried with above approach but coudn't able to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stops for each service are *not ordered* and we can't infer distances between stops, you can model the task trivially by creating `:Stop` nodes A, B, C, D, E, F, G and link them up with corresponding `:Service` nodes.

**Like this (representing only stops A, B, C and services 147, 196, 12):**

[image: partial graph]

You can then use one of the [path finding functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/pathfinding/) to get the result. For a single shortest path from B to C you could do

```
MATCH (start:Stop{name:'B'}), (end:Stop{name:'C'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end)
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).name AS name
```

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

EDIT:
To only check whether a direct route is available or not, you could query:

```
MATCH (start:Stop {name:"A"})-[]-(bus:Service)-[]-(end:Stop {name:"B"}) RETURN bus

This should return two result nodes
> (:Service {number: 196})
> (:Service {number: 12})
```

Comment: i understood this but at this stage i can't change my data model.
I need solution with extsing data model

Comment: it would be useful if you provided your actual data model then

Comment: I have added scrrenshot of my data model (shortest path A-D) which i am able to calculate .Actually in my data model there is no seperate node for buses.
I am associating bus(serviceNos) to node itself